# In Google Guava (Java), why are Iterables.getFirst() and getLast() inconsistent?

Tags: java, guava

From Google [Guava JavaDoc for `Iterables`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html):

```
static <T> T getFirst(Iterable<T> iterable, T defaultValue)
```

-> Returns the first element in `iterable` or `defaultValue` if the iterable is empty.

```
static <T> T getLast(Iterable<T> iterable)
```

-> Returns the last element of `iterable`.

```
static <T> T getLast(Iterable<T> iterable, T defaultValue)
```

-> Returns the last element of `iterable` or `defaultValue` if the iterable is empty.

One static method is missing (to me):

```
static <T> T getFirst(Iterable<T> iterable)
```

-> Returns the first element of `iterable`.

Do you know the reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because it's too simple to justify a helper method. The method would just be `iterable.iterator().next()` and would have behavior exactly analogous to `getLast()`.

Comment: Strictly speaking it would be `iterable.iterator().next()`, but I agree.

Comment: Ah of course, typed too fast. I'll fix that.

Comment: Still, when using methods like `Iterables.getLast()`, I'd assume the method to be present just for code readability and intent expression...