# Get first element of an async iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

On nodejs, I’m trying to get the first line of a file.
For that, I’m using the `readline` package as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/4948719).

But since I’m only trying to get the first line, I’d need to get the `readline` object to output its first element. I found how to do that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473826/why-there-is-no-getfirstiterable-method), but it looks like it only works for synchronous iterators.

How do you get the first element of an async iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return in the first iteration of the loop? Copying some code from that answer, and making sure [to destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277094/how-to-close-a-readable-stream-before-end) the stream after you're done with getting only the first line:

```
async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  for await (const line of rl) {
    fileStream.destroy();
    return line;
  }
}
```

and then `processLineByLine` will return a Promise that resolves to the content in the first line.