# Good way to get *any* value from a Java Set?

Tags: java, set, any

Given a simple `Set<T>`, what is a good way (fast, few lines of code) to get *any* value from the `Set`?

With a `List`, it's easy:

```
List<T> things = ...;
return things.get(0);
```

But, with a `Set`, there is no `.get(...)` method because `Set`s are not ordered.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

A `Set<T>` is an `Iterable<T>`, so iterating to the first element works:

```
Set<T> things = ...;
return things.iterator().next();
```

Guava has [a method](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getFirst-java.lang.Iterable-T-) to do this, though the above snippet [is likely better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832479/in-google-guava-java-why-are-iterables-getfirst-and-getlast-are-inconsist).

Comment: Actually, when you don't want a default, we want you to go ahead and use `iterator().next()`.  (This is why we don't have a `getFirst(Iterable<E>)`, just a `getFirst(Iterable<E>, E default)`.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Not necessarily.  If the set was very large, and had most of its items removed, it will need to loop through until it find a non-empty bucket. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046838/34397

Comment: True, but extremely rare in practice.  (Also, easily addressed by using a `LinkedHashSet`.)

Comment: (Also, I claim no faster solution exists.)

Answer (score 23):

Since streams are present, you can do it that way, too, but you have to use the class `java.util.Optional`. `Optional` is a wrapper-class for an element or explicitely no-element (avoiding the Nullpointer).

```
//returns an Optional.
Optional <T> optT = set.stream().findAny();

//Optional.isPresent() yields false, if set was empty, avoiding NullpointerException
if(optT.isPresent()){
    //Optional.get() returns the actual element
    return optT.get();
}
```

Edit:
As I use `Optional` quite often myself: There is a way for accessing the element or getting a default, in case it's not present:
`optT.orElse(other)` returns either the element or, if not present, `other`. `other` may be `null`, btw.

Comment: I wonder if this is faster or slower than `set.iterator().next();`.

Comment: set.iterator().next() will throw a NoSuchElementException in case the collection is empty, using findAny of Stream is safer since it'll give you an empty Optional if the the collection is empty. I would err on safety unless performance is really important. Really depends on what you need.

Comment: This solution is preferable for 2 reasons. (1) the forced null-checking with `Optional`, and (2) `.stream().findAny()` is much more self-documenting than `.iterator().next()`. I.e. it's much clearer that you're happy to get **any** element of the set, rather than just the "next" in the iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Getting *any* element from a Set or Collection may seem like an uncommon demand - if not arbitrary or eclectic - but, it is quite common when one, for example, needs to calculate **statistics on Keys or Values objects in a Map and must initialise min/max values**. The *any* element from a Set/Collection (returned by Map.keySet() or Map.values()) will be used for this initialisation prior to updating min/max values over *each* element.

So, what options one has when faced with this problem and at the same time trying to keep memory and execution time small and code clear?

Often you get the usual: "*convert Set to ArrayList and get the first element*". Great! Another array of millions of items and extra processing cycles to *retrieve* objects from Set, *allocate* array and *populate* it:

```
HashMap<K,V> map;
List<K> list = new ArrayList<V>(map.keySet()); // min/max of keys
min = max = list.get(0).some_property(); // initialisation step
for(i=list.size();i-->1;){
 if( min > list.get(i).some_property() ){ ... }
 ...
}
```

Or one may use looping with an Iterator, using a flag to denote that min/max need to be initialised and a conditional statement to check if that flag is set for all the iterations in the loop. This implies a lot of conditional checking.

```
boolean flag = true;
Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
while( it.hasNext() ){
  if( flag ){
    // initialisation step
    min = max = it.next().some_property();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    if( min > list.get(i).some_property() ){ min = list.get(i).some_property() }
  ...
  }
}
```

Or do the initialisation outside the loop:

```
HashMap<K,V> map;
Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();
K akey;
if( it.hasNext() ){
  // initialisation step:
  akey = it.next();
  min = max = akey.value();
  do {
    if( min > list.get(i).some_property() ){ min = akey.some_property() }
  } while( it.hasNext() && ((akey=it.next())!=null) );
}
```

But is it really worth all this manouvre on the behalf of the programmer (and setting up the Iterator on behalf of the JVM) whenever min/max's needed?

The suggestion from a javally-correct ol' sport could well be: "wrap your Map in a class which keeps track of min and max values when put or deleted!".

**There is another situation** which in my experience the need for just *any* item from a Map arises. **This is when the map contains objects which have a common property - all the same for all of them in that map - and you need to read that property**. For example suppose there is a Map of holding bins of the same histogram which have the same number of dimensions. Given such a Map you may need to know the number of dimensions of just *any* Histobin in the Map in order to, say, create another Histobin of the same dimensions. Do I need to setup an iterator again and dispose it after calling next() just once? I will skip the javally-correct person's suggestion to this situation.

And if all the trouble in getting the *any* element causes insignificant memory and cpu cycles increase, then what about all the code one has to write just to get the hard-to-get *any* element.

We need the *any* element. Give it to us!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, though it does elaborate on why the question makes sense.